# How do I export data into a file from Project-Tango device

Tags: android, file, camera, google-project-tango

As i mentioned in the title, i want to export information: RGB video, position,rotation of Tango and set of data point cloud, its depth as well into a file to analyse after.
I can separately extract these information following this guide: 
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c

but I don't know how to collect all infos by just one app (i.e combine all projects into one because there's conflict btw them).
Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following the common way to write in file. You just have to know where it's written. I don't remember exactly but it's the same for all android device, even for the tango (if you want it's also possible to use opencv on the tango to save it through cv::mat).
But I remember that when I did the same I wasn't able to write fast enough to save all data. So it may be the same for you

Answer (score 0):

So the trick is to create a single app that you enable all the features you want in the TangoConfig and also in your native code.

You then need to decide **when** you want to collect the data. Like will there be a GUI button to click, is it going to do it automatically, where is the file going to live, etc.? This logic can be implemented in the Java thread and passed down to a `getDataToFile()` native function call.

Most Tango data calls have callback functions when the data is ready. I would suggest **NOT** trying to save each data point as the DSP readings on Tango are gonna be WAY faster than what your file I/O will be. I would recommend a way of sampling the last position, rotation, point cloud, etc and then save to a file.

Not sure if a `fwrite` call will block execution so opening another thread **might** be needed. I would wait and see if you get a noticeable frame drop with a working implementation first.

If your struggle is the sample projects conliding, I would suggest starting a new project from scratch and add the features from the samples you want. If you need help getting a new project start [here is a tutorial to start a new project](https://github.com/sjfricke/Tango-C-NDK-Tutorial/tree/master/Section_04_Project)

**BIG NOTE:** make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
 in your manifest file!